# SUMPRODUCT With Multiple Criteria and Wildcard

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I have a **sumproduct** with multiple criteria and I like to have the option to skip some of these criteria

In SUMIFS, it is easy and can be done by replacing A,B,C with an * but it seems that **sumproduct** does not support that.

Here is the formula

```
SUMPRODUCT(--($I$6:$I$500="A"),--($B$6:$B$500="B"),--($C$6:$C$500="C"),$K$6:$K$500,L$6:L$500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I think I figured it out myself. Search function can help
I used these arguments to work around it

SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E5,$B$7:$B$506)),--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A5,$A$7:$A$506)),...

worked pretty well!